# Including some SFTP commands in a Makefile

Tags: command-line, makefile, sftp

I use a Makefile to create pdfs of papers I'm working on. I'd also like to use make to upload the latest version to my website, which requires sftp. I thought I could do something like this (which works on the command line) but it seems that in make, the EOF is getting ignored; i.e., this

```
website:
    sftp -oPort=2222 me@mywebsite.com << EOF
    cd papers
    put research_paper.pdf
    EOF
```

generates an error message

```
cd papers
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: papers: No such file or directory
```

which I think is saying "papers" doesn't exist on your local machine i.e., the 'cd' is being executed locally, not remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (normally) put a single command on multiple lines in a Make recipe, so here documents are a no-go.  Try this instead:

```
website: research_paper.pdf
    printf 'cd papers\nput $<\n' \
    | sftp -oPort=2222 me@mywebsite.com
```

The target obviously depends on the PDF, so I made it an explicit dependency, as well.

It's not that the `<< EOF` is "ignored"; it gets run by a separate shell which doesn't see the subsequent lines. Then `cd papers` is run in a new shell instance, which doesn't know anything about the previous command. This is a common Make beginner FAQ. (GNU Make has the `.ONESHELL` extension to run all commands in a recipe in a single shell command, but it's obviously not portable.)

Comment: One could also split the string across multiple lines which can improve readability. So printf 'cd papers\nput $<\n' \ can become 

printf 'cd papers\n \ <real newline here>
          put $<\n' \

Comment: Uh, a better solution then is probably `printf '%s\n' 'cd papers' \ ` (newline tab) `'put $<'`

Comment: jup, that indentation is so automatic I didn't even think to put it there :)

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ideas:

- use [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) which every Linux distro as well as brew should have: it remembers 'state' so the `cd` becomes unnecessary
- use `scp` instead of `sftp` if possible
- write a trivial shell script doing the EOF business and call that

For what it is worth, here is my script to push tarballs to the CRAN winbuilder -- and takes target directory and script as arguments to `ncftpput`.

```
#!/bin/bash

function errorexit () {
    echo "Error: $1"
    exit 1
}

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    errorexit "Need to specify argument file"
fi

if [ ! -f ${1} ]; then
    errorexit "File ${1} not found, aborting."
fi

ncftpput win-builder.r-project.org /R-release ${1}
ncftpput win-builder.r-project.org /R-devel ${1}
```

I then just do `wbput.sh foo_1.2-3.tar.gz` and off it goes...